# Execution of xpath expression fails in cloudHub -mule

Tags: xpath, mule, cloudhub

I've used below xpath expression in my code which works perfectly fine in local anypoint studio.

```
<set-variable variableName="item" value="#[xpath3('REQUEST/item',payload,'NODESET')]" doc:name="Variable"/>
```

Runtime version - 3.8.0

But after deploying code to CloudHub getting below error -

> Execution of the expression "xpath3('REQUEST/item',payload,'NODESET')"
>   failed. (org.mule.api.expression.ExpressionRuntimeException).

Please help me on resolving this issue.

Comment: Both in local and in Cloud using same version 3.8?

Comment: try backslash \

Answer (score 0):

You could try changing your statement from-

```
xpath3('REQUEST/item',payload,'NODESET')
```

to

```
xpath3('//REQUEST/item',payload,'NODESET')
```

or

```
xpath3('//item',payload,'NODESET')
```